# GetDIBits failing when trying to save screenshot with ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm attempting to take and save a screenshot using just `ctypes`. I'm not terrifically familiar with the Windows API, so I've been leaning pretty heavily on the various example in the Microsoft Developer Network.

I've been using the following code from the `MSDN` as a template to try to recreate with ctypes.

```
void  SaveBitmap(char *szFilename,HBITMAP hBitmap)
{

    HDC        hdc=NULL;
    FILE*      fp=NULL;
    LPVOID     pBuf=NULL;
    BITMAPINFO      bmpInfo;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER  bmpFileHeader;

    do{
        hdc=GetDC(NULL);
        ZeroMemory(&bmpInfo,sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize=sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        GetDIBits(hdc,hBitmap,0,0,NULL,&bmpInfo,DIB_RGB_COLORS);

        if(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage<=0)
            bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage=bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth*abs(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight)*(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount+7)/8;
        if((pBuf = malloc(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage))==NULL)
            {
            //MessageBox( NULL, "Unable to Allocate Bitmap Memory",
            break;
            }

        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression=BI_RGB;
        GetDIBits(hdc,hBitmap,0,bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight,pBuf, &bmpInfo,
        DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        if((fp = fopen(szFilename,"wb"))==NULL)
            {
            //MessageBox( NULL, "Unable to Create Bitmap File", "Error",
            MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
            break;
            }
        bmpFileHeader.bfReserved1=0;
        bmpFileHeader.bfReserved2=0;

        bmpFileHeader.bfSize=sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)+bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage;
        bmpFileHeader.bfType='MB';

        bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits=sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

        fwrite(&bmpFileHeader,sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,fp);
        fwrite(&bmpInfo.bmiHeader,sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,fp);
        fwrite(pBuf,bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage,1,fp);
    }while(false);

    if(hdc)     ReleaseDC(NULL,hdc);

    if(pBuf)    free(pBuf);

    if(fp)      fclose(fp);
```

However, I'm having terrible luck getting the `GetDIBits` function to succeed. I'm moderately confident that I've got the actual screengrab code correct, but the save code is giving me a lot of trouble. And frustratingly, I'm not sure *why* these functions are failing.

My Python code:

```
libc = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt

# handle to the entire desktop Window
hdc = windll.user32.GetDC(None)

# DC for the entire window
h_dest = windll.gdi32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdc)

width = windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
height = windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)

hb_desktop = windll.gdi32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height)
windll.gdi32.SelectObject(h_dest, hb_desktop)

print windll.gdi32.BitBlt(h_dest, 0,0, width, height, hdc, 0, 0, 'SRCCOPY')

# Save Section
# ==============
bmp_info = BITMAPINFO()
bmp_header = BITMAPFILEHEADER()
hdc = windll.user32.GetDC(None)

bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)
DIB_RGB_COLORS = 0
print windll.gdi32.GetDIBits(hdc, hCaptureBitmap, 0,0, None, byref(bmp_info), DIB_RGB_COLORS)

bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = bmp_info.bmiHeader.biWidth *abs(bmp_info.bmiHeader.biHeight) * (bmp_info.bmiHeader.biBitCount+7)/8;

pBuf = (c_char * bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage)()

BI_RGB = 0
bmp_info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB
print windll.gdi32.GetDIBits(hdc, hCaptureBitmap, 0, bmp_info.bmiHeader.biHeight, pBuf, byref(bmp_info), 0x00)

bmp_header.bfReserved1 = 0
bmp_header.bfReserved2 = 0

bmp_header.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage
bmp_header.bfType = 0x4D42

bmp_header.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)

fp = libc.fopen('test.bmp',"wb")

libc.fwrite(byref(bmp_header), sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, fp)

libc.fwrite(byref(bmp_info.bmiHeader), 
    sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, fp)

libc.fwrite(pBuf, bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, 1, fp)
```

I've added `print` statements to each `GetDIBits` call, and sure enough, they're all returning a failed code. I'm completely stumped here.

Comment: Use `sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)` and make similar fixes throughout your code. If `len(bytes(BITMAPINFOHEADER))` isn't rasing a `TypeError` then you're using 2.x and it's really `str(BITMAPINFOHEADER)`, i.e. something like `len("<class 'BITMAPINFOHEADER'>")`.

Comment: Let ctypes manage the allocation: `pBuf = (c_char * bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage)()`.

Comment: You don't need `fopen`; ctypes data types implement Python's buffer protocol; use a Python file.

Comment: Define the function prototypes with `restype` and `argtypes`, but maybe you cut that out for brevity.

Comment: @eryksun I made your suggested changes with the exception of using a Python file for the saving -- I tried `f = open('test.bmp', 'wb)` but that was throwing a `Don't know how to convert parameter 4` error. Since changing `len(bytes())` to `sizeof` the resulting file now appears to be filled with data (it's about 8mb). However, Windows says the file is empty if you try to open it with Picture Viewer. COuld you provide a little more detail on using a python file rather than `fwrite`?

Comment: Just write to the file. `with open('test.bmp', 'wb') as f: f.write(bmp_header); f.write(bmp_info.bmiHeader); f.write(pBuf)`.